# laravel schedule async tasks

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks

I'm quite new to Laravel so the question may be trivial... but I can't understand what is the best way to accomplish the following.
I have a simple application which allows users to schedule some tasks with different scheduling. The tasks and their scheduling are stored in a table (actually is a multi-tenant configuration, but shouldn't make a difference I think...)
These are the requirements:

1. the tasks are scheduled dynamically from the web interface
2. each tasks may take different time to complete, so they need to run separately from each other (async)
3. the tasks are recurring tasks (like crontab, run every x minutes, or
   x days)

From my understanding, I can accomplish this or with the Laravel task scheduler or with the Laravel queues...
Laravel tasks look simpler and satisfy requirements 1 and 3. I just don't understand if there is a way to run each task independently of each other. From my test, looks like PHP execute 1 task per time.
Laravel queues look more complicated for what I need and it's still not very clear to me how to create recurring jobs and how to dispatch the job every x minutes/days.. should I create a queue for each scheduling and scheduled tasks for the dispatcher?